# dynamic select options depend on another select option in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have two tables as users and departements. My departments table have two columns as id and title and my users table contains users information columns and one exta column as dept_id which is related to department table id.
I want to create a dropdown select option for departement and when a departement is selected the users which have that related department id should be displayed into another dropdown, how can i do that..?
 i am fetching all users and departments data in controller and sending it to view.

my controller is....

```html
    public function index()
    {
      $user = DB::table('users')->get();
      $dept =  DB::table('departments')->get();
      return view('userview', compact('user', 'dept'));
    }
```

and my view is....

```html
<select class="form-control" id="department" name="department" >
           @foreach($dept as $dept)
                 <option value="{{ $dept->id }}">{{ $dept->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
 </select>    
 
 
 <select class="form-control" id="user" name="user" >     
      <option>   </option>  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would use an Ajax request to fetch the related users and populate the 2nd list. Set up the relation in the `User` and `Department` models like:

```
// Department.php
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

// User.php
public function department() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

In your controller:

```
// DepartmentController.php
public function index() { 
    return view('userview', [
        'departments' => Department::all()
    ]);
}

public function users(Request $request, $id) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            'users' => User::where('dept_id', $id)->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, setup an event listener for the change event on the first select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="department" name="department" >
     @foreach($departments as $dept) 
        <option value="{{ $dept->id }}">{{ $dept->name }}</option>
     @endforeach 
</select> 

<select class="form-control" id="user" name="user" ></select>

<script>
    $('#department').on('change', e => {
        $('#user').empty()
        $.ajax({
            url: `/departments/${e.value}/users`,
            success: data => {
                data.users.forEach(user =>
                    $('#user').append(`<option value="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>`)
                )
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what is the route for this??