# Get data Based On Selected Value in Drop Down menu - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have two tables `posts` and `category`.

**My controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(['category']);
    $data = DB::table('posts')->paginate(5);
    $category = DB::table('category')->pluck('cname','id');

    return view('posts.index', [
        'posts'   => $posts,
        'category'=> $category,
        'posts'   => $data
    ]);
}
```

**My blade:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category_add">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>

    @foreach($category as $key=>$value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach                      
</select>
```

Now my code shows a drop down data from the database...

What I need is: When I select the drop down category it should only shows the particular category of data in the view dynamically

Any one help

Comment: Where in the view ?

Comment: Do you want to see my view...It's too large

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean after selecting a category from the dropdown there will be another section which will show data about that specific category?

One way to do it is through ajax request. I dont know if i got your question right or wrong. can u explain a bit if i got it wrong?

Comment: I have two types categories.It has to fetch the particular category id and show in the view page..

Comment: Are you wanting us to write code for you? A simple Google search easily shows you various ways to implement an AJAX request in every flavor of JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189276/dynamic-select-options-depend-on-another-select-option-in-laravel?answertab=oldest#tab-top                              - can you customize this code for me??